# If I have more files in one project I need to make all fields static?

Tags: java

If I make for example one project. Inside with two class. For example: X and Y. I make them what I want, and I want to make a main method in Y. Only system.out.printlf the values in X and Y. But it writes that I need to make them static if I want to run this. I tried to make a new file with only the main class and inside the X Y values but it showed an error. What I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main method is declared static

`public static void main(String[] args) {}`

Inside of `main`, it can only access static variables that exist in the enclosing class. You will see this for example with this bit of code:

```
public class X {
    private int i = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

To make the above work you need to declare `i` as `static`:

```
public class X {
    private static int i = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

A better way would be to do this:

```
public class X {
    private int i = 5;

    public X() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new X();    
    }
}
```

Static methods can only access static methods and other variables declared as static.

[This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) article may also help you to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

you have missed object creation. Try `X x = new X();` in your Y file. I would recommend to read some tutorials on Java, starting from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that's because everything happens inside the main method which is indeed static right? e.g.

```
public class C {
 int X;
 int Y; //or whatever other type
 ..
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   System.out.print( X ); //this won't work!
 }
}
```

instead use this aprroach:

```
public class C {
 int X;
 int Y; //or whatever other type
 ..
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   C inst = new C();
   System.out.print( c.X ); //this will work!
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main method is static and can *only* access static fields from the class. *non static* fields belong to an instance/object which you'd have to create:

```
public class X {
  static int a = 0;
         int b = 0;


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(a);   // OK -> accesses static field
    System.out.println(b);   // compile error -> accesses instance field
    X x = new X();
    System.out.println(x.b); // OK -> accesses b on instance of X
  }
}
```